# NoClassDefFoundError exception when trying to use SOOT

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, call-graph, soot

I'm trying to use SOOT to generate call graphs. However when I pass it some class to be analyzed, the exception NoClassDefFoundError is being thrown. I'm using the following two tutorials to be able to execute some of the commands:
http://www.brics.dk/SootGuide/sootsurvivorsguide.pdf and http://www.bodden.de/2008/08/21/soot-command-line/#obtaining.

I have placed the java source code to be analyzed in the same classpath of the SOOT. So when i'm about to execute, i used the "." to specify the current directory. The following is the command I'm executing:

```
java -cp jasminclasses-2.5.0.jar:sootclasses-2.5.0.jar:plyglot-1.3.5.jar:.soot.Main -cp . MainFrame
```

The same error is being generated even if I leave the -cp out and just call the MainFrame immediately.

does anyone know why this kind of exception is being thrown?

Comment: Add please full name of not found class.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoCLassDefFOundError: MainFrame
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MainFrame

Im assuming that the error is being generated because of the MainFrame itself and not because the soot.Main is generating some for of error.

Comment: Did you try to use full paths intead of relative?

Comment: i did and the same error is being generated

Answer (score 0):

The first classpath string looks weird and your actually not calling the `soot.Main` class. Give this a try:

```
java -cp jasminclasses-2.5.0.jar:sootclasses-2.5.0.jar:plyglot-1.3.5.jar soot.Main -cp . MainFrame
```

**Edit**

Regarding your last comment, it looks like a typical classpath error.

If you execute *your* line from the question above, Java tries to start the `main` method in class `MainFrame` (default package) - and can't find that class. With my (the correct!) command, java tries to find `soot.Main`.

Double-check your classpath again: you have to provide correct paths to the libraries. The actual command expects, that all three libraries plus `MainFrame.class` are in the current directory.

Comment: I've tried this form of input and in this case its giving me a NoClassDefFoundError on the soot/Main .... when i used the one I posted I even managed to get the help contents and version details so I'm guessing that that is not what has been generating the problem

Comment: *what* class isn't found, `soot.Main` or the analyzed class?

Comment: if i place your specified command in the command line, the error generated will name the soot.Main class. However the error generated when I use the command which I stated, an error regarding the analyzed class will be generated... so in this case the soot.Main is not generated an error i think